# How to improve whether there are objects in the condition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Due to the release of ES6, I would like to improve the code:

### Response examples:

```
// Ex: 1
response = false;
// Ex: 2
response = {};
// Ex: 3
response = {list: []};
// Ex: 4
response = {list: [{text: false}]};
// Ex: 5
response = {list: [{text: "some text"}]};
```

#### Code example

```
if (response && response.list && response.list.length>0 && response.list[0] && response.list[0].text){
    // Some actions
}
```

#### or

```
if (response && response.list && response.list.length >= 64){
    // Some actions
}
```

How to make this code shorter without repetitions:

```
response && response.list && response.list.length>0 && response.list[0] && response.list[0].text
```

Comment: You can write a function that checks the response `function isResponseOk(response) { return (//your validation here) };` and do `if(isResponseOk(response)){//some actions};`

Comment: There's no es6 feature which will make the validation easier

Comment: @DomeTune I have written a more detailed question

Comment: @MixerOID unfortunetly you cannot shorten your validation much more. The only things which is not needed is `response.list[0]`, because if the `length of list` is greater than `0` there has to be an element at `response.list[0]`. Updated & bit shorter: `response && response.list && response.list.length>0 && response.list[0].text`

Comment: This may come into existence in the not-too-distant future with the proposed null propagation operator, but it is currently not implemented even by Babel (though I think a solution has been submitted).

Comment: @DomeTune `response.list[0]` for check `([undefined])[0]`; try `var a = [undefined]; if(a.length>0 && a[0].text){ console.log('test') }` in console and you will got the error

Comment: @MixerOID sorry, i did not saw this example in your question. So i did not mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to shorten it to

```
try {
  if (response.list[0].text) ...
} catch (err) {}
```

but it is inadvisable to use it in performance-critical places.

Lodash/Underscore `get` already has this functionality and can be used (available as separate `lodash.get` package):

```
if (_.get(response, 'list[0].text')) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly you cannot shorten the `if-statement` but ss mentioned in the comments you can put it into a function, if you need the `statement` more than once.

```
function isResponseOk(response){
    return (response && response.list && response.list.length>0 && response.list[0].text);
}
```

You wont need to repeat the `statement` anywhere else, you can use it by:

```
if(isResponeOk(response){ //do stuff };
```

Comment: I don't have problem with total code repeat, I have many long different conditions. Move the condition to any place isn't a solution, unfortunately.